# R changes format of number after writing .csv

Tags: r, csv, format

I have data containing latitude and longitude coordinates. 
In R it looks correct, but when I write it as .csv it changes the format.

from: 52.0286 and 5.10374

to: 520.286 and 510.374

In other words, it changes the position of the dot. How can I avoid this from happening? Thank you for your reply

Comment: what happens when you just try to save these columns on their own? What is the code you use now to save to csv?

Comment: Without any sample data or the code you used, it is impossible to reproduce your problem or provide a meaningful answer.  Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1 as a good reference on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens. One temporal solution is to write data into string type.

A reproducible example is here.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
    write_excel_csv('tmp.csv')
```

Created on 2018-11-02 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).